# SQL Server Error: "%" is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint. See previous errors

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005, and am relatively new to SQL in general.

There is a relationship between two tables, "Resources" and "Group_Resources", in the database "Information".  Resources has a foreign key, "id", in Group_Resources, named "resource_id".  There is a foreign key constraint, "fk_gr_res_resources", between the two.

I'm established as the database owner, and have full read/write/create/delete permissions.

I want to delete the foreign key constraint, so I executed the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE [Information].[group_resources] DROP CONSTRAINT fk_gr_res_resources
```

and received the following error:

```
'fk_gr_res_resources' is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

I'm confused, because it is a constraint, and there are no spelling errors.  Am I going about deleting this improperly?  Am I deleting the constraint from the incorrect table?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the constraint from the other table? That would answer your question about whether you're deleting it from the right place.

Comment: Yes- I've tried deleting the constraint from both "gropus_resources" and "resources". I still get the same error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are getting this error:

```
Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'fk_gr_res_resources' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

***Because the FK constraint does not exist!***

*Are you sure that* `Information` *is the right schema name and not* `dbo`?

**1. This SQL will prove that the FK does not exist:**

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'fk_gr_res_resources'
```

**2. Oops, I was wrong in my original answer, here is the correct syntax for SQL Server:**

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
DROP CONSTRAINT <foreignkey_name>
```

**3. Example for your database:**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'fk_gr_res_resources')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE Group_Resources
  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_gr_res_resources
END;
```

**4. Try running this:**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'fk_gr_res_resources')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE Group_Resources
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_gr_res_resources
  FOREIGN KEY (resource_id)
  REFERENCES Resources(id) /* make sure Resources.id is a PRIMARY KEY */
END;
```

**5. Then try this and see if you still get that error:**

```
ALTER TABLE Group_Resources
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_gr_res_resources
```

*The other syntax was for MySQL, sorry:*

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name>
DROP FOREIGN KEY <foreignkey_name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. I put in the following:

"ALTER TABLE <table_name>
DROP FOREIGN KEY <nameOfMyForeignKey>"

and it gave this error:

"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOREIGN'."

Same deal with the 2nd example. (everything is spelled properly, by the way, so I'm not sure why I keep getting errors: the syntax looks correct.)